# Long distance (16 hours) car trip with rental car and driver

Tags: usa, car-rentals, road-trips

I want to go to Riverton (WY) from Seattle (WA). Last time I went by flight but this time I want to go (and return) by car. Problem is I do not know driving and all my searches are giving me links to rental services where I need to drive the rental car. Uber seems only to allow 4 hours travel and don't see an option of multi state journey. I can find some bus routes but I would prefer Car.

The journey would take about 16 hours driving so I am planning to stay one night in a road side hotel. I am OK to split the trip in two if it helps.

Train Journey is also fine and actually encouraging for me and I am ready to lose one more day in each side if it is by train.

Comment: Given enough money, there's bound to be a car service out there that will do it for you, but it's going to be awfully expensive for 16 hours of a car+driver's time, the driver's time for the overnight stay, hotel rooms for you and the driver, meals, tip, and whatever the heck the driver wants to charge to get back to Seattle. If that's something you want, I'd start searching for car services in Seattle and asking for quotes, but I would expect it to cost several thousand dollars. Are you sure that's what you're looking for? A private car?

Comment: There is no passenger train service anywhere in the state of Wyoming (see route map at https://www.amtrak.com/train-routes), so that idea is a non-starter.  Even with Thruway Bus the closest you can get is Rawlins, 120 miles away, and that requires a long detour through California.

Comment: I am OK if the car is shared like a carpool but where I don't have to drive. Though I was getting some car sharing options from Seattle to Salt Lake City there are not much from Salt Lake City to riverton.

Comment: So what are the options if I want to go by road without driving my own car? I checked Greyhound bus but they also don't have stop at riverton. Is there a way to go to a nearby town (Which town?) and get some kind of private car from there?

Comment: Salt Lake City is 200+ miles out of the way. You could try posting on [Seattle's Craigslist](https://seattle.craigslist.org/search/rid) to look for a ride, but I wouldn't be very optimistic at all about finding someone who happens to want to go to a random town in Wyoming 16 hours away when you want to travel.

Comment: I suspect there basically aren't any options.  In rural areas of the US the default assumption is that people will have their own cars and drive themselves around.  The infrastructure / culture is really not designed for anything else.  If you can't drive I think you pretty much have to fly and count yourself lucky that the town actually has an airport with scheduled flights.

Comment: There simply aren't very many transportation options there (as Nate just said!). Getting out to Casper or Jackson and scheduling [a shuttle](http://sharearidewyoming.com/BoardingTimes.html) to Riverton is probably your best bet if you don't want to fly into Riverton.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I will probably have to take the flight to Caspar or Salt Lake City and get some shuttle from there.

Comment: Could you take a bus to Montana, then take the Amtrak from there?  Not sure if buses in Montana go that far north.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you are looking for is commonly known as a *rideshare* or *carpool*, i.e. a ride in someone else's private car where you might compensate the driver for expenses. Unfortunately, because Riverton is a small town in a remote and unpopulated area, I think it is extremely unlikely you will be able to pair with someone driving all the way to Seattle. There are likely to be people in the area who make trips to closer cities however, among them Jackson, Caspar, Billings, or Salt Lake City, which have better connections.

Some services that try to match drivers and riders include [Rdvouz.com](https://www.rdvouz.com/), [Ridesharing.com](https://www.ridesharing.com/i), and [Kangaride](https://www.kangaride.com/); I have not used any of them and do not vouch for them, but they are worth a try. The best-known name in this sector was Tripda, but unfortunately they shut down in early 2016; Ridejoy is also long gone. Zimride remains, but you must be affiliated with a participating institutional partner (e.g. employer, university) to use it.